# What is the recommended way to work with a distutils-based setup.py of a C extension?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers has now completely replaced instructions for `distutils`-based packages (starting with `from distutils.core import setup`) with ones for `setuptools`-based ones (starting with `from setuptools import setup`).

However, if I have a `distutils`-based `setup.py`, when I run it, `setuptools` is not used - thus the instructions on the page don't work.

It is possible to run a `distutils`-based script through `setuptools`, as `pip` does, but [it requires the following code](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/8.1.2/pip/req/req_install.py#L849):

```
python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__=<setup.py full path>;
    exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read()
    .replace('\\r\\n', '\\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" <setup.py arguments>
```

They can't possibly expect me to type that on the command line each time, now can they?

Comment: I see you asked this also in [comp.lang.python](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/kMUk1HdLTG8) as well. I've researched this recently and come to conclusion that they now recommend distributing wheels rather than sdist's. This seems reasonable for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the time of asking, https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers has been updated to include instructions for `distutils`. The gist is:

- `distutils` only detects the basic compiler setup (typically, the compiler included with the corresponding version of Visual Studio). Sections of the guide corresponding to those setups explicitly mention `distutils`.
- For other setups, it can be run from the "Windows SDK command prompt" and be told to rely on environment variables set by it by also setting the `DISTUTILS_USE_SDK` environment variable.

  - Under the hood, it also checks for the `MsSdk` environment variable that is set by MS's SDK command prompt scripts.